# Initial input for completing-read

Tags: completing-read

With the following function using "completing-read", how can one add a default initial input to be `Convert`. What can I do?

```
(defun subset ()
  "Convert or extract subsets of data."
  (interactive)

  (let* ( (opts '("Convert" "Split"))
          (sel  (completing-read "Subset: " opts nil t  )) )
```

Comment: The initial-input can be given as the 5th argument to the `completing-read` function. You can find that using  `C-h f`. And, while typing the `completing-read` form, the expected arguments are displayed in the echo area. Or do you mean something else? I am not sure what is your goal, but if you have only two options, you could also consider to use the `universal argument`.

Comment: I would just enter "Convert" as the 5th argument or something else?

Comment: Yes just enter that

Comment: Thank you friend.

Comment: I am actually encountering a slight problem.  I add "Convert" and run the function.  What happens is that "Convert" appears as expected.  But when I go through the option, the first one that appears is also "Convert".  Making it seem like the option is stuck to  "Convert".

Comment: I think that is the only option when using 'plain' completing read. If you would like to see the other options also, then you can better use some 'completion package/framework', like [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), [vertico](https://github.com/minad/vertico) etc. Then the first 'candidate' could be considered the default.

Comment: A limitation of `completing-read` I assume.

Comment: Well, it seems like I did not read thoroughly enough. I assume that, what you want, is the second case in Drew's answer. So, no limitation of `completing-read`, also not a shortcoming of the documentation. Just a limitation of our patience to read the function it's documentation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean use `Convert` as the *initial input* then this is how:

```lisp
(let* ((opts  '("Convert" "Split"))
       (sel   (completing-read "Subset: " opts nil t "Convert")))
  (message "SEL: %s" sel))
```

If you really mean use `Convert` as the *default value* then this is how:

```lisp
(let* ((opts  '("Convert" "Split"))
       (sel   (completing-read "Subset: " opts nil t nil nil "Convert")))
  (message "SEL: %s" sel))
```

If you really mean use `Convert` as *both* the *initial input* and  the *default value* then this is how:

```lisp
(let* ((opts  '("Convert" "Split"))
       (sel   (completing-read "Subset: " opts nil t "Convert" nil "Convert")))
  (message "SEL: %s" sel))
```

In the initial-input (only) case `Convert` is preinserted into the minibuffer, and the default, if you remove that preinserted input, is the empty string, `""`.

In the default (only) case `Convert` is not inserted -- you use `M-n` to insert it. And if you just `RET` without inserting any text then you get `Convert`.

In all three cases, just hitting `RET` chooses `Convert`. `Convert` is an allowed completion because you decided that it belongs to `opts`, which you pass as the allowed completions.

If you remove `Convert` from `opts` and change the `t` value of arg `REQUIRE-MATCH` to `nil`, then `Convert` isn't a completion but it is accepted as an input. Anything at all is accepted as an input, in this case.

It all depends on what you want.  If you have a more specific question, please pose that separately.

Comment: Reading the docstring of `completing-read` for `INITIAL-INPUT` - which says that the argument is deprecated - telling users to pass `nil` and supply the default value `DEF` instead.

Comment: Your comment isn't a sentence. What about such reading?

Comment: That the suggestion on using initial-input could became a problem in future.